# how to reload UIPicker elements - iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have seen many application reloading table data & table.

My Question is "Is it possible to re-load a picker view elements?"

[tableView reloadData];

this statement - refreshes the tableView,

How this is possible in UIPickerView elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your buddy. :)

http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006842-CH3-SW10

Answer (score 3):

use UIPickerView reloadComponents or reloadAllComponents check it out here 
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html